# Can I use the stock SMS/MMS app on an Android tablet without UMTS module?

Tags: sms, tablet, mms, lenovo-thinkpad-tablet

I just got my Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet. It does not have a GSM/UMTS/3G module but there is an SMS/MMS icon. What is the purpose of this app? Does Android allow me to send and receive SMS/MMS over my Wifi Internet connection, or is it just a leftover?

I am not interested *in any alternatives* to the stock app. I am more curious if it serves any purpose on a device without a UMTS module and if so, how to configure and use it.

So the questions could also be phrased like: **What purpose serves the stock Android SMS app on an tablet without GSM/UMTS module?**

Comment: I can't speak to the stock app or the device in particular, but it depends on whether your carrier has something like [UMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Access_Network#UMA.2FGAN_Beyond_Dual-mode) for extending services like SMS over the public Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for now I consider the stock SMS/MMS app a leftover on tablet devices without an GSM/UMTS module. I serves no purpose on such devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can download an app such as TextPlus from the market for free and then send MMS & SMS from that app. I am not sure what app you are talking about since I don't have a ThinkPad tablet but I know that you can use TextPlus.

Comment: Ayman: It looks like the Tablet has the original Android SMS/MMS app installed and it claims to be able to send and receive SMS although I have no UMTS module and couldn't find any preferences regarding configuration of the app (SMS-Call center ID, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Another app/service to try would be [Google Voice](http://voice.google.com).  You can get a phone number and send/receive SMS (and voicemail).  This may only work (or work well in the US, though).

Comment: P.T.:Thanks for you answer. :) But I am not asking for alternatives to the stock app. I edited my question and made that more clear.