# Can I receive / send SMS of cellphone number with a tablet using a dongle?

Tags: sms, tablet

Can I receive / send SMS of cellphone number with an Android tablet using a dongle? Any SMS application for the Android tablet?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, madhukar! I've attached the fitting tags to your question. Browsing the [questions using these tags](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tablet+sms), you will find the information you're after: [Sending sms from tablet not allowed or not possible?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17028/16575) and [Can I use the stock SMS/MMS app on an Android tablet without UMTS module?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13964/16575) should prove helpful.

Comment: Just want to point out that this is not a duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13964/16575 This question is about using a dongle whereas the other one is about what you can do with the SMS app on a tablet **without using a dongle**.

Answer (score 2):

Very probably not.

Reason: While (some?) USB dongles do support sending/receiving SMS, Android doesn't have a means to make use of it as is. 3rd party SMS apps rely on the Android API, but your device's firmware is very probably not built to expose 3G dongle's SMS capabilities via that API.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is http://mightytext.net/ , it can provide you with access to your mobile phone sms & mms.  There could be probably more have a look..

Comment: I've used Mightytext between my Chromebook and my phone It's very good (assuming your phone has data enabled, or is at least connected to wifi, because your phone ultimately acts as the relay for the sending/receiving of the texts).