# How to allow making and receiving calls & texts using SIM card on tablet?

Tags: applications, calls, tablet

I have an Android tablet without a telephone app. I can put in a SIM card and use the data on it. I also want to use the phone number from the SIM. When somebody calls my SIM card (mobile number), it rings and goes to voicemail.

How can I receive this call? And texts? What application do I need?

Comment: If it was designed for data only like most tablets then what you want to do can't be done, with or without apps.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. We have some related questions about this: [Can I make and receive phone calls using a tablet with a SIM card slot in it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/22034/44325), [Calls and texts in tablet with mini-USB SIM adaptor](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/53177/44325). A possible case is that your tablet doesn't support GSM phone functionality, meaning that no apps will help the situation, sorry.